# enableViewStateMac="true" FAILS to Validate _ViewState

Tags: asp.net, performance, security

I have my web application where I have set the **enableViewStateMac="true"** under  attribute in **web.config**. I was trying to validate different security aspects of view state.

However, there is one scenario, where **enableViewStateMac="true"** fails to validate the _**ViewState** has been changed. I am using the `"TamperData" plugin of Firfox browser`. Using Tamperdata, I completely remove the value of _VIEWSTATE and then POST the web request. The POST request gets posted successfully and page redirects to the next page successfully without any error.

Though, as per my knowledge and security testing so far for enableViewStateMac="true", It seems to me the EnableViewStateMac only works/validate `weather _VIEWSTATE is being tampered or not`. But it `doesn't validate if _VIEWSTATE Value is being deleted/removed completely`.

Is there is a way I can validate this also (that is if someone has completely removed the value of _VIEWSTATE)?

Thanks in advance,
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

When the page is generated, store a value in ViewState.  Then, on post back, read that value back out.  If __VIEWSTATE isn't present you'll receive a null value back at read time.

Comment: Yes, That's true. But it would not give any error or warning that someone has removed the _ViewState value. Page do load successfully. Only affected area is that control wouldn't able to get previous state filled after PostBack.

Comment: Better question for you: in the *general case*, why should the page fail if there's no view state submitted?  It's just treated as a non-postback scenario in that case.  If your scenario has specific requirements that you require view state to be present, this is something you'll have to check for manually and fail if you think the request state is invalid.